# arr is not defined in Javascript Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

the following code is supposed to count the number of heads vs tails. The code below was given to me but I was tasked with counting heads vs tails, I tried with the function function countHeadsAndTails(flips) and below but running into a small issue. I have triple asterisked the line that is giving me an error: arr is not defined (under the function countHeadsAndTails(flips)) I'm sure this is just a silly mistake and I'd hate to waste your time with such an easy fix but I've been banging my head against the wall for the past 30 mins trying to solve it, thanks :)

```
var NUM_FLIPS = 100;

var headCount = 0, tailCount = 0;

function start(){
    var flips = flipCoins();
    printArray(flips);
}

// This function should flip a coin NUM_FLIPS
// times, and add the result to an array. We
// return the result to the caller.
function flipCoins(){
    var flips = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < NUM_FLIPS; i++){
        if(Randomizer.nextBoolean()){
            flips.push("Heads");
        }else{
            flips.push("Tails");
        }
    }
    return flips;
}

function printArray(arr){
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        println(i + ": " + arr[i]);
    }
    countHeadsAndTails();
}
function countHeadsAndTails(flips) {
    for (var i = 0; i < NUM_FLIPS; i++) {
    ***if (arr["flips"] === "heads")***
        headCount += arr[i];
    else
        tailCount += arr[i];
}
print("Heads: " + headCount + " " + "Tails: " + tailCount);
}
```

Comment: Hi, your problem is that arr isn't in the scope of the function you call it. In the only place you have declared the arr value is in the printArray() function.

Comment: @OscarVelandia Isn't arr just calling the array?

Comment: If the script had a variable in the scope of the countHeadsAndTails() function called arr, arr would be called, but in this case, the function doesn't have any variable called arr.

Comment: @OscarVelandia Yup I got it now after watching a couple videos and you tube and the explanations posted here thanks

Comment: @Ivan86 Done. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not declared the `arr` array as global, therefore you have to pass it to functions that are supposed to use it. The `arr` array is actually `flips`. I changed your code below to pass the array to the `countHeadsAndTails()` function and also added a couple other small changes to the same function (see arrows below).

**Run and test:**

```js
var NUM_FLIPS = 100;

var headCount = 0, tailCount = 0;

function start(){
    var flips = flipCoins();
    printArray(flips);
}

// This function should flip a coin NUM_FLIPS
// times, and add the result to an array. We
// return the result to the caller.
function flipCoins(){
    var flips = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < NUM_FLIPS; i++){
        if( Math.round(Math.random()) ){  //  <- To mimic Randomizer 
            flips.push("Heads");
        } else {
            flips.push("Tails");
        }
    }
    return flips;
}

function printArray(arr){
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        console.log(i + ": " + arr[i]);
    }
    countHeadsAndTails(arr);             //  <- passing array to function 
}

function countHeadsAndTails(flips) {     //  <- array is now called flips again
  for (var i = 0; i < NUM_FLIPS; i++) {
    if (flips[i] === "Heads")            //  <- check the ith element, and capital H
        headCount++;                     //  <- increment headCount
    else
        tailCount++;                     //  <- increment tailCount
  }
  console.log("Heads: " + headCount + " " + "Tails: " + tailCount);
}

start();
```

**Note:** I also changed `print()` and `println()` to `console.log()` in order to be consistent with correct JavaScript output syntax.

Comment: Thank you sm!! I got it now, watched a couple youtube videos too